# How to iterate between dates in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, date

I have two dates, fromDate and toDate. 
Say, txtEffectiveDate is 26/02/2013 and txtInactiveDate is 28/02/2013, I need to have my headers in jsp as `26/02 27/02 and 28/02`. I have written a util function which returns the difference in days. This is what i have so far achieved.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1">
            <tr>    
                <td width="100" class="boxBorderHeader141">Service NO.</td> 
                <% long diff= 0 ;
                    diff = DateUtil.getDifference(DateUtil.toUtilDate(request.getAttribute("txtEffectiveDate").toString()), DateUtil.toUtilDate(request.getAttribute("txtInactiveDate").toString()));
                %>  
                <td width="100" class="boxBorderHeader141"><bean:write name="servicesForm" property="txtEffectiveDate" /></td>                              
                <td width="100" class="boxBorderHeader141">Departure Time</td>
                <td width="100" class="boxBorderHeader141">Depot Code</td>
                <td width="100" class="boxBorderHeader141">Service Category</td>
                <td width="100" class="boxBorderHeader141">Service Name</td>  
                <td>&nbsp;</td> 
            </tr>
            </table>
```

The dates should iterate between Service No. and Departure time ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your scriptlet, calculate further dates

**Your code**

```
long diff= 0 ;
diff = DateUtil.getDifference(DateUtil.toUtilDate(request.getAttribute("txtEffectiveDate").toString()), DateUtil.toUtilDate(request.getAttribute("txtInactiveDate").toString()));
```

**Extension**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
for(int i=0; i < diff; i ++){
     cal.setTime(DateUtil.toUtilDate(request.getAttribute("txtEffectiveDate").toString()));
     cal.add(Calendar.DATE, i + 1);
     java.util.Date newDate = cal.getDate();
     //     Display that new date as column
}
```